# Python HTML Parser (Unnamed Level)

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a screen scraper to pull football statistics down from [www.pro-football-reference.com](http://www.pro-football-reference.com).  I'm currently scraping from the main player's stat page and then diving into their individual page with their statistics by year.

I was able to implement this process successfully with my first set of players (quarterbacks, using the Passing Table).  However, when I attempted to re-create the process to get running back data, I am reciving an additional column in my data frame with the values "Unnamed: x_level_0".  This is my first experience with HTML data so I'm not sure what piece I missed, I just assumed it would be the same code as the quarterbacks.

**Below is the QB Code sample and the correct dataframe:**

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import lxml
import re
import csv
p = 1

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com'
year = 2020
maxp = 300

#Passing Data
r = requests.get(url+ '/years/' + str(year) + '/passing.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

results = soup.find(id='div_passing')
job_elems = results.find_all('tr')

df = []
LastNameList = []
FirstNameList = []


for i,row in enumerate(parsed_table.find_all('tr')[2:]):
        dat = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat': 'player'})
        if dat != None:
            name = dat.a.get_text()
            print(name)
            stub = dat.a.get('href')
            

            #pos = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat': 'fantasy_pos'}).get_text()
            #print(pos)

            # grab this players stats
            tdf = pd.read_html(url + stub)[1]
            for k,v in tdf.iterrows():
                #Scrape 2020 stats, if no 2020 stats move on
                try:
                    FindYear=re.search(".*2020.*",v['Year'])
                    if FindYear:
                        #If Year for stats is current year append data to dataframe

                        #get Name data
                        fullName = row.find('td', {'class':'left'})['csk']
                        findComma = fullName.find(',',0,len(fullName))
                        lName = fullName[0:findComma]
                        fName = fullName[findComma + 1:len(fullName)]
                        
                        LastNameList.append(lName)
                        FirstNameList.append(fName)
                        #get basic stats
                        df.append(v)
                except:
                    pass
```

This output looks like the following:

```
Philip Rivers
Year      2020
Age         39
Tm         IND
Pos         qb
No.         17
G            1
GS           1
```

**Below is the RB Code sample and the incorrect dataframe:**

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import lxml
import re
import csv
p = 1


url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com'
year = 2020
maxp = 300

#Rushing Data
r = requests.get(url+ '/years/' + str(year) + '/rushing.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

results = soup.find(id='div_rushing')
job_elems = results.find_all('tr')

df = []
LastNameList = []
FirstNameList = []


for i,row in enumerate(parsed_table.find_all('tr')[2:]):
        dat = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat': 'player'})
        if dat != None:
            name = dat.a.get_text()
            print(name)
            stub = dat.a.get('href')
            print(stub)
            

            #pos = row.find('td', attrs={'data-stat': 'fantasy_pos'}).get_text()
            #print(pos)

            # grab this players stats
            tdf = pd.read_html(url + stub)[1]
            for k,v in tdf.iterrows():
                print(v)
                #Scrape 2020 stats, if no 2020 stats move on
                try:
                    FindYear=re.search(".*2020.*",v['Year'])
                    print('found 2020')
                    if FindYear:
                        #If Year for stats is current year append data to dataframe

                        #get Name data
                        fullName = row.find('td', {'class':'left'})['csk']
                        findComma = fullName.find(',',0,len(fullName))
                        lName = fullName[0:findComma]
                        fName = fullName[findComma + 1:len(fullName)]
                        
                        LastNameList.append(lName)
                        FirstNameList.append(fName)
                        #get basic stats
                        df.append(v)
                except:
                    pass
```

This output looks like the following:

```
Unnamed: 0_level_0   Year       2020
Unnamed: 1_level_0   Age          26
Unnamed: 2_level_0   Tm          TEN
Unnamed: 3_level_0   Pos          rb
Unnamed: 4_level_0   No.          22
Games                G             1
                     GS            1
Rushing              Rush         31
                     Yds         116
                     TD            0
```

An example URL where this data is pulled from is: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/J/JacoJo01.htm

And it is pulling the Rushing & Receiving.  Is there something additional I need to be on the lookout for when it comes to parsing HTML?

I attempted to add index_col = 1 into my tdf = pd.read_html(url + stub)[1].  However, that just kind of grouped the two values into one column.

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.  If I can provide any further information, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code to parse the table passing for each player (Now I get the players from https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/passing.htm but you can pass any player URL to it:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def scrape_player(player_name, player_url, year="2020"):
    out = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(player_url).content, 'html.parser')

    row = soup.select_one('table#passing tr:has(th:contains("{}"))'.format(year))
    if row:
        tds = [player_name] + [t.text for t in row.select('th, td')]
        headers = ['Name'] + [th.text for th in row.find_previous('thead').select('th')]
        out.append(dict(zip(headers, tds)))

    return out

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/passing.htm'
all_data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
for player in soup.select('table#passing [data-stat="player"] a'):
    print(player.text)
    for data in scrape_player(player.text, 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com' + player['href']):
        all_data.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Creates this csv:

[image]

---

EDIT: To parse Rushing&Receiving, you can use this script:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


def scrape_player(player_name, player_url, year="2020"):
    out = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(player_url).content, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one('#rushing_and_receiving_link').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment)), 'html.parser')

    row = soup.select_one('table#rushing_and_receiving tr:has(th:contains("{}"))'.format(year))
    if row:
        tds = [player_name] + [t.text for t in row.select('th, td')]
        headers = ['Name'] + [th.text for th in row.find_previous('thead').select('tr')[-1].select('th')]
        out.append(dict(zip(headers, tds)))

    return out

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/passing.htm'
all_data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
for player in soup.select('table#passing [data-stat="player"] a'):
    print(player.text)
    for data in scrape_player(player.text, 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com' + player['href']):
        all_data.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Creates this CSV:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so much more efficient and works like a dream.  If you don't mind can you confirm my understanding of how this works?  In scrape_player, for the row variable I set the tag of the data I want to extract and then change the variables in my url and soup.select to be the correct stat I'm looking for (passing, rushing, receiving etc, depending on it's tag in the HTML). This is incredible!

Comment: @MCJNY1992 Yes, every table has unique ID, so change `#passing` for some other table and it should work the same.

Comment: Am I to use the value between <h2></h2>? The Rushing & Receiving is named Rushing & Receiving, which is creating an Python error for invalid character.

Comment: @MCJNY1992 See my edit how to parse the Rushing&Receiving table (the actual table is stored inside HTML comment `<!-- ... -->`, so you have to parse it from there).

Comment: I see, I'll have to research into that later.  I switched over to no longer read the Rushing table instead of the Passing tables and added a Try/Except in the scrape players.  Weirdly enough I'm still only getting quarterbacks that qualify under the Passing table in my dataframe.  I can see it looping through the Runningbacks from the rushing table but somehow my dataframe only ends up being players from the Passing table.

Comment: I figured it out, the table is only commented for QBs, so the lambda function was False, I updated my code that if the row variable == None, then simply just pull the table, removing the lambda function.